# Error when trying to edit a Telegram message

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I have a list of items which I select one randomly and send it to the user. Then, I have an inline button just below the text message to shuffle the list of items once again.

Like this:

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
shuffle_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Shuffle Again', callback_data='shuffle_action')
keyboard.add(shuffle_button)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['shuffle'])
def display_shuffle(message):
    cid = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(cid, random_song(), reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Then I've made a callback query handler that changes the contents of the sent message if the user requests to randomize it once again:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: c.data == 'next_action')
def shuffle_more(call):
    cid = call.message.chat.id
    mid = call.message.message_id

    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=cid, message_id=mid, text=random_song(), reply_markup=keyboard)
```

The enormous problem I'm having with this is that sometimes the `random_song()` function I'm using to shuffle the list sometimes randomly returns the same exact message as I've displayed the previous time. Since you cannot edit a message to the same message, I get an error.

How can I change my code so this does not happen?
P.S. I'm using the pyTelegramBotAPI wrapper in py3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution I've come up with, but it works:

```
chosen_song = random_song()

while True:
    try:
        bot.edit_message_text(cid, mid, chosen_song)
    except:
        chosen_song = random_song()
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) contains the current [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) and therefore has a field `text` containing the current text.

You should be able to read the current text with `call.message.text` and adapt the `random_song()` to make sure it's not the same.

Comment: the text I send is formatted in HTML. I've tried that, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Notice that `call.message.text` will contain the unformatted text, without any HTML or markdown tags. So you can directly compare `random_song( )` with `call.message.text`.

Comment: the `random_song()` returns a string that has html tags. I then send it with `parse_mode='HTML'`. Therefore I can't compare both of these strings.

Comment: Then you'll have to work with some sort of helper function